# D3js json structure

Tags: json, d3.js

I'm doing some charts with analytics regarding a game. Here is the basic assumptions.

There are three possible actions a player can make.
Player can attack
Player can deffend

Player can run ( in 2 directions forwards and backwards)

Each action can happen in one of the three battlegrounds (bg a, bg b, bg c)

A player can be human or alien. Each player regarding of race can have a level.

Each player executes a particular action at a particular time.

Now i need to chart these things.

Piechart of the players race
Piechart of where the actions took place(in which of the 3 battlegrounds)
A barchart of the players level
A line chart for attacks based on time
A line chart for defends based on time
A linechart for runs( oneline for each direction of running) based on time

Each chart needs to be connected to the other ones (kondof the crossfilter flight charts are) . So for example if i click on the piechart with the player race and chose human the other charts update accordingly to reflect levels, and battlegrounds and actions pertaining just to that race.

Bottom line is i am having a hard time structuring my json input. Can any experts give me some hints? 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: You are not going to find one data structure that meets the needs of all your charts. You should build an API that gives you back just what you need for each chart.

Comment: Problem is Graham that all charts should be connected.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, the most flexible way is to build up an array of "events" (an event can be anything a player might do) with timestamps. Something like:

```
var playerEvents = [
  { timestamp: 1352848500, player:'human', action:'attack', location:'bg A' },
  { timestamp: 1352848600, player:'alien', action:'run', meta:'dir=left', location:'bg B' },
  ....
]
```

Once you have that, any stats you want display would involve filtering this array of events down to whatever you need for the given graphic.

Comment: Thanks meetamit. That's kinda the way I was thinking about it yes. But it wouldnt be a problem if the same player has multiple events in this scenario correct?

Comment: I don't see how it would be an issue. It's an array of events. It can be filtered down to smaller arrays of multiple events that satisfy a condition (e.g `action == 'run' && player == 'human'`). The Crossfilter flights example uses [similarly formatted data](http://square.github.com/crossfilter/flights-3m.json). (I should say i haven't used Crossfilter yet).